# ng-class calling function on page load - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This may be very simple but I can't seem to be able to successfully get the logic I want.

```
<div class="group-title" ng-class="{'group-hasError': !isValid(orderItem)}">
```

As you can see I'm adding a class `group-hasError` if the function `isValid(orderItem)` returns false.

Now the issue is that this is called on page load. But I don't want to call this function on page load rather when a submit button is called

```
<button id="add_modified_item" ng-click="isValid(orderItem)" class="btn btn-primary btn-fixed-medium pull-right">
```

How can I achieve this?

This is the function;

```
$scope.isValid = function(orderItem) {
  var count = 0;
  //By default make it true
  var IsAllSelected = true;
  angular.forEach(orderItem.menu_modifier_groups, function(group) {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach(group.menu_modifier_items, function(item) {
      count += item.selected ? 1 : 0;
    });
    if (count == group.max_selection_points) {
      IsAllSelected = true;
    } else {
      //if one item failed All select do return false
      IsAllSelected = false;
    }
  });
  return IsAllSelected;
}
```

Any advice appreciated

Comment: you can bind model value `$scope.setValidClass=false` default and on set model value on `isValid`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi in the code you gave me?

Comment: Is it inside in form?Your button is not Submit button

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN just button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defalut set

```
$scope.setValidClass=false;
```

View

```
<div class="group-title" ng-class="(setValidClass)? 'group-hasError':'')}">
```

set model with

```
//if IsAllSelected=false then set IsAllSelected to  true
$scope.setValidClass=!IsAllSelected;
return IsAllSelected;
```

Comment: Perfect bro... Appreciate it!